# How to do session management for OpenID Connect?

Tags: javascript, java, security, session, authentication

I'm trying to use OpenID Connect for auth but I'm not sure how to do session management after I get, extract and validate the info from the ID Token.

The steps I followed so far are as described in Google's [OpenID Connect Docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) except step: **6. Authenticate the user**.

What would be the best method for doing session management?

**Ideas:**

- **1.** Send the ID token or access token to the client (browser/javascript) store it in session storage and send it only over https to the server in the Authentication header like this:

  *Authentication: Bearer YzNHxEdi118B.QlhOY21sdVp3.0zcHlkR1ExY*

  Also if it's not valid I should request a new one through the refresh token?
- **2.** Write another session management system on top of the existing one based on JWT (Isn't that a bit of unecessary overhead>).

*If in the future it's needed to add more providers (facebook, twitter) that use another auth system like oauth wouldn't I need to implement another session management system on top of the existing one?*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some weeks ago so I ended up implementing a session system at the end that uses the verification step from openID to do the authentication.

I ended up using JWT with refresh tokens and access tokens. The access token would expire every 5 mins and then you would have to use your refresh token to get a new access token.

Comment: The refresh, access token idea is pretty good and I have seen it on another question as an answer. The confusing part for me is the "verification step from OpenID". Maybe you mean the validation of the ID token?